# Terminal Server 2008 Closing All Applications Immediately Upon Opening

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server, remote-desktop-services, windows-terminal-services

I've got a terminal server that one user is having problems with. Everyone else seems to work just fine. When this user tries to open any application, it closes immediately. This is ALL applications. Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Office applications, etc... I have no idea what the issue could be. At first, I thought it was because the TS was not issuing licenses correctly, and there was event ID 4105 in the logs. I have since fixed that issue, but the issue still persists. I tried creating a new user profile for him, and the problem still persists. There are no event logs related to the apps crashing, and the same apps work for all the other users that utilize the server. Any ideas?

Comment: Block all GPO for that user, and try again to open a session.

Comment: Still happens with all GPOs disabled for this user.

Comment: Tried to connect from another computer ?

Comment: The user and I are at different locations and it happens at both.

Comment: Nothing seemed to work, so I created a new user account for this person in Active Directory and remapped all drives and printers. Something is wrong with that users account and I didn't feel like digging around for the problem.